# Converting all lowercase characters to uppercase in x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I have taken a recent interest in learning assembly and proposed myself to do a simple exercise, which is to take a simple string and convert all the lowercase characters to uppercase. But as I'm fairly new to this I can't get my head around some details and make it work.

```
EXIT = 1
WRITE = 4
LINUX_SYSCALL = 0x80
.data          
lowerA: .ascii "a"
lowerZ: .ascii "z"
msg:    .ascii  "Hello, world!\n"   
msglen = (. - msg)
i: .int 0

.text           
.global _start   
 _start:

movl    lowerA, %eax
movl    lowerZ, %ebx
movl    $msglen, %edx
movl    $msg, %ecx
mov     i,  %esi

A1: 
    cmp %edx, %esi
    jz fim 
    cmp %eax,(%ecx)
    jge lowerThanZ
    jmp next_pos



lowerThanZ: 
    cmp  %ebx,(%ecx)
    jle capitalize
    jmp next_pos

#esta subrotina e que vai fazer a acao necessaria para mudar a letra para maiusculo
capitalize:
        #THIS WOULD BE WHERE I WOULD CONVERT LOWERCASE TO UPPERCASE

    jmp next_pos        


#sub-rotina para fazer o incremento do counter, do registo e voltar para o inicio de A1
next_pos:   
    add $1, %ecx
    inc %esi
    jmp A1


#acaba aqui
fim:    
sub     %edx, %ecx
movl    $1, %ebx
movl    $WRITE, %eax    # pedir write ao sistema
int $LINUX_SYSCALL  # chama o sistema
movl    $0,%ebx             
movl    $EXIT,%eax      # pedir o exit ao sistema    
int     $LINUX_SYSCALL  # chama o sistema
```

You can see that the code is not complete, but I know that it doesn't work
as I've been using gdb(also something I'm fairly new to) to debug it.

I already saw that the looping is correct (the string is printed in the end, but in it's original state).The thing is that it doesn't enter the capitalize sub-routine when it is supposed to.
I know I can use the ASCII values to see which ones match to capital letters. But I still did not understand how to do it properly. From the amount of research I've done I understood that if we have a String/array in a register, the register is pointing to the first position of said string, and if I use (%register) I'll get the contents of that address.

So I am trying to use cmp to do exactly that, trying to see if the current char is a lowerCase (between a-z). And I know that it's in the cmp statements that things go wrong but I cannot understand why

Probably I am missing something big, so I would be really appreciated for any help.

I am using Assembly IA-32 on Linux and have been using the following commands to assemble and link :

```
as --32 -g -o hello.o hello.s

ld -m elf_i386  -o hello hello.o
```

Comment: You're comparing memory addresses, not letters. Comparing letters would look something like `cmpb $'a', (%ecx)`.

Comment: Okay that does work! Thank you! But a followup question, I tried to use  first a variable in .data containg 'a' in the cmpb and the following error appears in the linker : "relocation truncated to fit .data". Any ideia why this happens?
Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: 8086 is the 16-bit ancestor of IA-32.  386 introduced the IA-32 architecture, which is why 32-bit mode on Linux is often called i386.

Comment: Related: [How to access a char array and change lower case letters to upper case, and vice versa](//stackoverflow.com/a/35936844)

Comment: `movl    lowerA, %eax` is a bug: you're doing a 32-bit load, so you're getting 3 extra bytes of data beyond the `"a"` at `lowerA`.  If you only use `%al`, then the high garbage in EAX doesn't come into play, but you need to understand that in assembly language it's up to you to load/store with the right width to match what you put in static memory locations.  If you want a zero-extending byte load into a 32-bit register, use `movzbl lowerA, %eax`.  But seriously, there's no reason to store small constants like that in memory instead of using immediates unless you want to change them at runtime